# What is the most appropriate way to calculate the successive discount of a price?

Tags: java, math

Example:

> Price: **100$** | Discount: **10%** | Successive discount: **5%**

The successive discount applies to the price after the discount, so I'm doing something like this:

```
float price = 100f;
float disc = 10f;
float sucDisc = 5f;
float finalPrice = (price * (1f - (disc / 100))) * (1f - (sucDisc / 100));
System.out.println(finalPrice);
```

Output:

```
85.5
```

This seems to be correct, but this is a very old problem and I'm probably reinventing the wheel, so I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this. By better I mean a method that improves readability, efficiency and/or accuracy.

Comment: I don't see why any other form would be easier to read... I'd use this code as is, though if you want you could mathematically simplify the `(1-disc/100)*(1-sucDisc/100)` part, that would probably be less efficient programatically though (counting the number of calculations 5 versus 7 if I am not mistaken).

Comment: Also, you probably won't be happy with the accuracy of your calculations if you use floats. Use BigDecimal instead, or better yet, the Joda Money library - http://www.joda.org/joda-money

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, that's the way to do it. You probably shouldn't be using `float` though.

From [the specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> This data type should never be used for precise values, such as
>   currency. For that, you will need to use the java.math.BigDecimal
>   class instead.

`BigDecimal` might be overkill for the example you gave, but for large currency values, `double` will break down fast and `float` will break down faster.

One more thing: in general, never use `float` unless you specifically want to save space. It is about half as precise which can lead to some pretty bad results.